# Aumentar Fonte da pagina

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde,

Possuo uma tabela e dentro dele chamo um iframe em que dentro dele chamo um outro site. Tenho uma função em javascript para aumentar e diminuir fonte dos componentes da pagina, porem tudo que está dentro do iframe não é alterado.

Código JS:

```
$('.BTAumentarFonte').click(function () {
        //span
    $('.TBMainTableMP2 span, .TBMainTableMP2 p, .TBMainTableMP2 a, .TBMainTableMP2 div, .form-control, .TBMainTableMP2 iframe').each(function(){
        var tamFonteAux = $(this).css('font-size');
        var tamAux = tamFonteAux.length;

        var tamFonte = parseInt(tamFonteAux.substr(0, tamAux - 2));
        //if((tamFonte > 21) || (tamFonte < 10)){tamFonte = 10;}

        if (tamFonte < 22) {
            $(this).css('font-size', tamFonte + 1 + 'px');
        }
    });        

});

$('.BTDiminuirFonte').click(function () {
    //span
    $('.TBMainTableMP2 span, .TBMainTableMP2 p, .TBMainTableMP2 a,.TBMainTableMP2 div, .form-control, .TBMainTableMP2 iframe').each(function(){
        var tamFonteAux = $(this).css('font-size');
        var tamAux = tamFonteAux.length;        
        var tamFonte = parseInt(tamFonteAux.substr(0, tamAux - 2));     
        //if((tamFonte > 21) || (tamFonte < 10)){tamFonte = 11;}

        if (tamFonte > 10) {
            $(this).css('font-size', tamFonte - 1 + 'px');
        }
    });
});
```

Essa TBMainTableMP2  é a minha classe da tabela e dentro dela quero pegar a tag iframe e aumentar as fontes que tem dentro. Alguem sabe dizer o que preciso alterar para funcionar ?

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Cara, vc não vai conseguir isso por causa do CORS.

Comment: CORS? O que seria?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS